# Stack Overflow on Slack

Tags: discussion

Does stackoverflow.com have a channel on slack.com or are only chat rooms available at chat.stackoverflow.com? I tried to Google it, but I do not see any relevant answers.

Comment: Ask questions about the site itself on StackOverflow Meta.

Comment: Nothing official.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if there are channels on Slack that are formerly managed/controlled by SE staff. I do know a few users that are also active on Slack but that is about it. There is no formal or endorsed way for Slack Channels here on SO.

The only chat rooms that are linked to and moderated by the Stack Overflow community are the chat rooms you'll find on https://chat.stackoverflow.com.

Keep in mind that all chat rooms here, as opposed to Slack, are public (except moderator rooms) and their transcript is readily available for everyone to read, even when not logged in. There is the option for Gallery rooms to control who can talk in a room but there is no option to create private rooms unless you have a diamond.